# XSLT2.0-Group Adjacent not copying text()

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm grouping adjacent 'inline' elements with the following XSLT 2.0  but none of the text() nodes are copied, does anyone know why?
Source xml:

```
    <para>
      <p>some text</p>
      <section>
       <section>
        <inline>inline text</inline>
        <inline/>
        <p>some more text</p>
        <p/>
       </section>
       <para>
        <p>dog</p>
        <p/>
        <p/>
        <sub-para>
            <p/>
            <p/>
        </sub-para>
       </para>
      </section>
    </para>
```

My XSLT 2.0 stylesheet has 2 template matches (for text()) and * (for any element)

```
    <xsl:template match="text()">
     <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::inline)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <grp><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></grp>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

The results I currently get are:

```
    <para>
     <p/>
     <section>
      <section>
       <grp>
        <inline>inline text</inline>
        <inline/>
       </grp>
       <p/>
       <p/>
      </section>
      <para>
        <p/>
        <p/>
        <p/>
        <sub-para>
         <p/>
         <p/>
        </sub-para>
       </para>
     </section>
    </para>
```

i.e. elements are copied, adjacent inline elements are grouped, but no text nodes are copied.

Why doesnt calling apply-templates select=current-group() result in the text() template being called?

Many thanks for any answers

Answer (score 0):

The instruction `<xsl:for-each-group select="*"` selects the child element nodes, and not the child text nodes. So the text nodes will not be part of any group, and are therefore not copied.

The fact that you have a template rule that matches text nodes is irrelevant, because you never apply templates to a text node.

If you change the for-each-group to select text nodes as well (by writing `select="node()"`) this has the problem that the "inline" elements will no longer be adjacent, because they are separated by whitespace text nodes.

I don't know the source vocabulary, but my inclination would be to use the grouping template only for "block-level" elements such as para and section, and use a standard identity template for elements that have text or mixed content.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Michael Kay says, you are only ever selecting elements, not nodes, and so your text nodes will not ever be processed.

As the current template you have matches elements, and then processes child elements, I think what you need is a second template that also matches elements, but only ones with no child elements. In this template you can then add your handing for text nodes

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Because this template has a condition specified, it should, I believe, take priority over your existing template when the condition is true.

Actually, it could even be simplified to this

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

It is also worth pointing out that your current template matching **text()** is not actually needed, whether you apply templates to a text node or not. XSLT has the concept of built-in templates which are used when there no explicit template match for a node is found in the XSLT. These built-in templates will output text nodes if ever used anyway, so all your "text()" template is doing is what the build in template would do anyway.

Comment: Thanks Tim, That approach wont work for mixed content, like this:'code'<p><inline css:font-size="11" css:fullstyle="b">Table </inline><inline css:font-size="11" css:fullstyle="b">A:</inline> For Example</p> where the two inline elements are to be joined. The text is lost.  Its such a simple requirement but I have spent days so far trying to solve it with XSLT 2

Comment: Are you sure the text is lost, because it seems OK to me, although I may have misunderstood the exact requirement! I think it could help if you could edit your question to show an example with "mixed content", and more importantly, show the output you expect in this case. Thank you!